# Rails 3 - Thumbs_up - customized button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, customization, vote-up-buttons

Hi
I've installed the Thumbs_up gem and it works great.

But now I want to do a button that does the same as this.

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_retailer_path(@retailer), :remote => true, :method => :post) %>
```

The problem I got is that I want a image and a text inside the button with the text "Like <%= @retailer.title %>", (like youtubes like button).

The button I have is coded like this.`

```
<button role="button" class="like">
  <img src="/images/layout/blank.gif"><span>Like <%= @retailer.title %></span>
</button>
```

How can I accomplish the button with these features in rails3?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood that correctly, but to add a variable inside your text, you can do :

```
link_to "vote for this #{@retailer.title}" ...
```

For the image you can use image_tag :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your fast reply, your answer is part of the solution I guess.

I want rails to render the code I pasted in my question "<button role="button..." but I don't know how to get the image and span inside the button?

Comment: Wrap everything around the link_to. Just add the html as you have it and inside the span add your link_to as i've shown :)

Comment: Hi,
I've changed it to this, but it doesn't register any votes when clicking on the button.

<button role="button" class="like">
  <img src="/images/layout/blank.gif"><span><%= link_to("vote for #{@retailer.title} !", vote_up_retailer_path(@retailer), :remote => true, :method => :post) %></span>
</button>

Comment: try without the remote and also check your posted action.

Comment: Hi tried that and it didn't do anything, it's like the buttons taking over and doesnt apply the link? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: it should work. check the html to see if it's parsed correctly.

Comment: Hi, This is what I got:

<button class="like" role="button">
  <img src="/images/layout/blank.gif"><span><a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/retailers/retailer1/vote_up">vote for retailer1 !</a></span>
</button>

Comment: Well,, I made an alternative to the initial request...

It's not perfect but it works, the irritating thing is that I have to make the background with the icon instead of separating them as I did before. But it works :)

      <% form_tag({:action => 'vote_up'}, :remote => true) do %>
          <%= submit_tag "Gilla #{@retailer.title}!", :class => 'like' %>
      <% end %>

      <% form_tag({:action => 'vote_down'}, :remote => true) do %>
          <%= submit_tag "", :class => 'disLike' %>
      <% end %>